# Unable to comprehend graph of aqueous lithium bromide vapour pressure

Tags: vapor-pressure

$\ce{LiBr}$ $Vp$ chart:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/x77zc8wj11gthsj/LiBr_Vp.jpg

or

http://www.mediafire.com/view/u4dnocvbsf3atmu/Useful_Chart_LiBr.pdf

Lecture in question (p.13)

http://www.mediafire.com/view/gly78yz339hv1x1/RAC_Lecture_15.pdf

[image]

In the lecture it says that at this temperature & at this concentration crystallisation will occur... however how can this be ascertained using the chart? I do know how to read such Duhring plots..